# Serving PHP website with Nginx doens't work. Is my code or my setup wrong?

Tags: php, sql, database, connection

I'm trying to serve a simple website with PHP code in it. The URL is (example) `https://myphpwebsite.com` and it is served with Nginx running on a Ubuntu 18.04 VM with PHP and phpmyadmin installed. I'm using another device on my LAN running letsencrypt and nginx to create certificates and route traffic to the correct device on the network. I tried everything i'm going to talk about below on Apache as well and i got the same result.

- Using my own code (listed below), trying to connect to a database, results in the website not loading at all.
- I can go to `https://myphpwebsite.com/phpmyadmin` so I know the domain is working.
- Doing something simple as `<php echo "string";` workes and the website loads.

  This leads me to believe that something is wrong with my code, or something wrong with the other Nginx doing the signing and routing. However, I am actually serving this exact website with a company, using their hosting. They are the ones also hosting the SQL database at the moment, but I'm trying to move everything to my server.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php

    $serverIP = "10.x.x.x";
    $dbusername = "x";
    $dbpassword = "x";
    $dbname = "x";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverIP, $dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname);
    if(mysqli_errno($conn)) {
     die("<p>MySQL error:</p>\n<p>" . mysqli_error($conn) . "</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
    }  
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
    <body>
      <h1>Works</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

`curl -I https://myphpwebsite.com` gives me this error:

```
HTTP/2 504 
server: nginx
date: Sat, 16 Mar 2019 13:26:59 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 176
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains; preload
```

Comment: Check your web servers error log and see if there's any error messages that can give you some clues.

Comment: have you allowed the connection on the firewall?

Comment: Do i have to specifically allow php in my firewall? Otherwise i have set up the firewall with the HTTP method, since the server it self is only listening on port 80.

Comment: /var/log/nginx/error.log shows no errors.
/var/log/nginx/access.log shows me GET the site from my browser.

Like so: 
192.x.x.x - - [16/Mar/2019:14:11:34 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "https://myphpwebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/x.x.x.121 Safari/537.36"

Comment: presumably the db server on the 10.x.x.x address is not the same server as the web server on whatever public ip it is accessed through. Your PHP connection script is trying to make a connection to port 3306 so as a starting point check that the connection is not being blocked at the firewall.

Comment: That makes sense. The hosting provider probably doesn't allow access to the database if the website is not on the same network. Thank you. But why does the website take so long to load (or not load) ?